# Retain a single git branch for a few closely-related Pull Requests?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

We are working on an open source project and typically have a few active Pull Requests.

It is straightforward to create one branch per pull request:

- main:  "clean" replica of upstream.  this NEVER has any of our custom repo changes. It is regularly rebase'd from upstream and contains no commits of ours
- feature1:  put only the commits associated with the Pull Request for feature1 here
- feature2:  put only the commits associated with the Pull Request for feature2 here
  ..
- featureN:  put only the commits associated with the Pull Request for featureN here

But I was wondering if others of you out there have been successful with managing multiple features/PR's in a single branch - and how you configured same.

- main: "clean" replica of upstream
- featureset1:  put a few different closely-related features/PR's here
- featureset2:  put another set of closely related features here

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do this a lot and I call the *integration branches*. create a branch based off of the branch the pull requests merge to (usually `master`) then merge each pull request branch in what ever order you wish.

This is a throw away branch in that it doesn't matter in the end if it lives or not because as the pull requests are merged the same commits are rolled into master and eventually you can just delete the integration branch.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git checkout -b int/all-the-pull-requests
$ git merge user1/feature-1
$ git merge user2/feature-2
$ git merge user3/feature-3
```

If you want to add more from that you can branch again and after the pull requests are merged into master then `rebase --onto` to move the commits to be based off of master.

```
$ git checkout -b feature/after-integrations
$ git add .; git commit
...
$ git checkout master
$ git pull # pull requests were merged!
$ git checkout feature/after-integrations
$ git rebase --onto master int/all-the-pull-requests feature/after-integrations
$ git branch -D int/all-the-pull-requests # No longer needed
```

Handle changes on individual pull request after you created an integration branch.

```
$ git checkout user2/feature2
$ git pull
$ git checkout int/all-the-pull-requests
$ git merge user2/feature2
```

If you had

```
A--B--C (master)
    \  \
     \  D--F (feature1)
      \
       G--H (feature2)
```

Would become

```
A--B--C (master) I------------J (int/all-the-pull-requests)
    \  \        /            /
     \  D------F (feature1) /
      \                    /
       G------------------H (feature2)
```

And an update to feature2:

```
A--B--C (master) I------------J--L (int/all-the-pull-requests)
    \  \        /            /  /
     \  D------F (feature1) /  /
      \                    /  /
       G------------------H--K (feature2)
```

Merge

```
A--B--C------M------------N (master) 
    \  \    /            /
     \  D--F (feature1) /
      \     \          /
       \     I--J--L  / (int/all-the-pull-requests)
        \      /  /  /
         G----H--K--/ (feature2)
```

And delete

```
A--B--C------M--N (master) 
    \  \    /  /
     \  D--F  / (feature1)
      G--H---K (feature2)
```

Comment: Hi Sukima, please clarify your specific workflow here. We have changes affecting mutiple PR's simultaneously.  Let us  assume the files in each PR are all mutually exclusive.  How do you handle the pushes for the individual PR-related files?  Do you cherry pick? How is that working out for you?

Comment: do a `git pull` for the pull request branch then merge again. a merge will only update changes since last merge. If it get confusing I delete the integration branch and do it again.

Comment: Hi I upvoted since this is helpful. But I do not understand some of the detail: maybe some more commentary.  You seem to have a bunch of different feature branches:  "userN/feature-N", as well as int/all-the-pull-requests.  The relationship is not clear to me.

Comment: We use "git rebase" and do not use git pull or git merge since that causes confusion/redundancy with the dozens (or sometimes hundreds) of commits invoked by other users on the upstream repo.

Comment: I don't understand how `git pull` is an issue. Are you using a custom git configuration that changes the pull defaults?

Comment: You'd have to offer an example if done correctly there shouldn't be any redundancy. You could also use `git pull --rebase` for that.

Comment: After doing git pull or git merge then we can not simply do git push: it pushes the prior unrelated commits as well.

Comment: Ahh, That is from divergent branches and instead you should do a `git fetch` and `git merge` to an integration branch like described above.

Comment: It is not clear that you are addresing my original question.  Your diagrams above show each of the feature's in their own branch UNTIL AFTER MERGE. That is not what I was asking.